# CRUD strongly typed data access

Tags: c#, design-patterns, sql-server

I have a data access class:

```
using CompanyX.DataAccess.CompanyXTableAdapters;

namespace CompanyX.DataAccess
{
    public class CompanyXDataAccess
    {
        #region Invoice

        public CompanyX.InvoiceDataTable GetInvoiceByID(int ID)
        {
            InvoiceTableAdapter ta = new InvoiceTableAdapter();
            using (ta.Connection = new SqlConnection(DB.GetReaderConnectionString()))
            {
                return ta.GetByID(ID);
            }
        }

        public CompanyX.InvoiceDataTable GetInvoice(string userSID)
        {
            InvoiceTableAdapter ta = new InvoiceTableAdapter();
            using (ta.Connection = new SqlConnection(DB.GetReaderConnectionString()))
            {
                return ta.Get(userSID);
            }
        }

        public void DeleteInvoice(int ID)
        {
            InvoiceTableAdapter ta = new InvoiceTableAdapter();
            using (ta.Connection = new SqlConnection(DB.GetWriterConnectionString()))
            {
                ta.Delete1(ID);
            }
        }

        public void UpdateInvoice(Invoice m)
        {
            InvoiceTableAdapter ta = new InvoiceTableAdapter();
            using (ta.Connection = new SqlConnection(DB.GetWriterConnectionString()))
            {
                ta.Update1(m.ID, ... n numbers of params ..., m.ModifiedBy);
            }
        }

        #endregion

        // more regions for modules come in here with CRUD and other queries
    }
}
```

[image]

Is there any way I can improve this code without losing any performance?

**Please note:** I had to change names in code and trim screenshot for company privacy reasons.

Comment: Can I ask why you would prefer to use stored procedures?

Comment: You're looking for a design review it seems. I think you'd receive better answers on Programmers.SE

Comment: There might be potential, for sure. But Code Review is here to *review* already written and working code! Once you have something built that works, bring it here and we'll help you out! :)

Comment: I guess you're right. I checked with my folks on the chat and it seems that question is okay!

Comment: To me it sounds like that you are really asking for a design pattern for separating reads and writes. Maybe you are looking for a basic implementation of [CQRS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn568103.aspx) on the data access level.

Comment: I believe too much detail was making this question boring, so I trimmed it down now to be more on point

Answer (score 3):

**Readability**

- Use namespace `CompanyX` instead of using in every method's return type.
- Create single instance of `InvoiceTableAdapter` and `SqlConnection` and reuse it.
- In `UpdateInvoice` method, instead of passing multiple properties, pass data model itself and use properties which are required inside `Update1` method.
- You will need to put the cleanup of the connection in a `Dispose()` after making the data access class `IDisposable`. As pointed out by [ratchet freak](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/32061/ratchet-freak) in another answer.

Not sure why you're using 2 SQL connections. I would suggest you to use only one.

After refactoring code should look like this:

```
    using CompanyX;
    using CompanyX.DataAccess.CompanyXTableAdapters;

    namespace CompanyX.DataAccess
    {
        public class CompanyXDataAccess : IDisposable
        {
            InvoiceTableAdapter ta = new InvoiceTableAdapter();
            SqlConnection readerConnection = new SqlConnection(DB.GetReaderConnectionString());
            SqlConnection writerConnection = new SqlConnection(DB.GetWriterConnectionString());

            public InvoiceDataTable GetInvoiceByID(int ID)
            {
                ta.Connection = readerConnection;
                return ta.GetByID(ID);
            }

            public InvoiceDataTable GetInvoice(string userSID)
            {
                ta.Connection = readerConnection;
                return ta.Get(userSID);
            }

            public void DeleteInvoice(int ID)
            {
                ta.Connection = writerConnection;
                ta.Delete1(ID);
            }

            public void UpdateInvoice(Invoice m)
            {
                ta.Connection = writerConnection                                    
                ta.Update1(m);
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                // Do clean up
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort +1, But I have lots of Table Adapters though as mentioned in the code comments, that will end up me ending 5 - 10 table adapters makes it look like a code smell - I think

Comment: @Mathematics then make this class generic and parameterize the adapter and table types. Should work pretty well for you.

Answer (score 2):

- Please read: [Are #regions an antipattern or code smell?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/53086/are-regions-an-antipattern-or-code-smell)
- Instead of retrieving the connectionstrings for reading and writing each time any of this methods are called, you should retrieve them once and store them in meaningful named variables.
- Instead of explicitly declaring the type e.g `InvoiceTableAdapter ta = new InvoiceTableAdapter();` you should make use of the `var` type because it is obvious by the right hand side what type is assigned. In addition having a name like `ta` doesn't tell much about its meaning/usage, so you should consider changing that name.

Answer (score 1):

You keep recreating both the adapter and the connection, instead cache them after first creation.

You will need to put the cleanup of the connection in a `Dispose()` after making the data access class `IDisposable`.